# try to count this online user's order which is processing

Tags: mysql, join, woocommerce

I want to limit each user to register only one order per day.

To do this, I need to check each user's order before registering whether this user has any 'wp-processing' order or not?

I wrote below MySQL query in PHP, but it doesn't work.

I printed value of '$sql_count_from_status' and try it in phpmyadmin, SQL tab to find the error.
Value of the variable was:

```
SELECT count(ID) FROM wp_posts p LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta m ON p.ID=m.post_id WHERE p.post_status LIKE 'wc-processing' AND p.post_type LIKE 'shop_order' AND m.meta_key LIKE '_customer_user' AND m.meta_value LIKE '100577';
```

and showed me zero in phpmyadmin as result. Now I know the query has problem, because I had 'processing order' for user 100577.

```
function get_orders_count_from_status( $status , $this_user_id){
global $wpdb;

// We add 'wc-' prefix when is missing from order staus
$status = 'wc-' . str_replace('wc-', '', $status);

$sql_count_from_status = "
SELECT count(ID)  FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts p
LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta m
ON p.ID=m.post_id
WHERE p.post_status LIKE '$status' AND p.post_type LIKE 'shop_order'
AND m.meta_key LIKE '_customer_user' 
AND m.meta_value LIKE '".$this_user_id."';";

return $wpdb->get_var($sql_count_from_status);
}
```

Comment: `AND m._customer_user LIKE '".$this_user_id."` Move this line to somewhere else. And see about prepared and bound queries

Comment: It was my bad, I corrected the query.

Comment: Nope. That's not it. Somewhere *else*!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of a plausible query (although counting on a LEFT JOIN is a bit strange):

```
SELECT count(*)  
  FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts p
  LEFT 
  JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta m
    ON m.post_id = p.ID   
   AND m.meta_key = '_customer_user' 
   AND m.meta_value = :this_user_id
 WHERE p.post_status LIKE :status
   AND p.post_type = 'shop_order'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it solved the problem. Now if I want to get all orders for specific customer_user id, which its type is 'shop_order' and has completed status and has specific _completed_date, how could be the query? (for example userid:100577, status:completed, post_type:shop_order, _completed_date:2019-11-29) The problem is I should use two m.meta_key and two m.meta_value and don't know how.

Comment: If you have a new question, ask a new question, referencing this one

Comment: Ok, thank you for your advise. How can I reference new question to this one?

Comment: You can paste this page's url into the text of your new question